# React js Socket io not working in Local area network wifi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io-1.0

So I have a finished nodejs + socket.io + reactjs project that is working on my machine. I can open different tabs or browsers in my machine and test it out, and its working. However I wanted to test it on other machine within my local area network. When I connect it through the wifi on other machine to my network ip address, I can see the page. However, the socket.io is not working. When I open the console in chrome (other machine), this is the error I see:

> GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LMXV0Uf net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This is my node app-server.js:

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.static('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist'));
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

How can I solve this issue? Also what is the recommended way to deploy in production so that socket.io will work.

Comment: The other machine might be pointing to your web server via browser url, but it says right there that it's trying to connect to `localhost`, which is the other computer. Your client side socket connection also needs to point to the machine where the server resides. Is this intended to run over LAN or are you just trying to test it out?

Comment: @azium Hello azium. No, I was just testing it on my LAN. Sorry, I am only a beginner. What do I do to solve this? Do I make the app/socket.io listen to the network ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to the socket app.. the stuff that lives on some single server somewhere, and the client side code that gets distributed to other computers, who need to connect back to the server to make the socket connection.

Your server code probably does not need to change. If you're able to reach it via some IP address that means it's serving correctly.

Let's say you can access the website via http://1.2.3.4:3000

Somewhere in your client side code you'll have something like:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
let serverUrl = 'localhost:3000'
let socket = io(serverUrl)
```

You'll need to change `serverUrl` to the ip address of your server, so `http://1.2.3.4:3000`

This is because `localhost` when loaded from another computer is pointing to *that* computer.. but you need to make the socket connection back to the original server.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. Now I know more about socket io and nodejs.